# Spectral centroid range between 0.45 to 0.5, almost doesn't react to mic input

Tags: frequency-spectrum

I am implementing some feature extractors in Swift for an application. One of these features is Spectral Centroid. For some reason I keep getting values ranging between 0.45 and 0.5, and these don't really reflect what I'm playing through the microphone. I can see why it's close to 0.5 when there is nothing playing as the centre of mass is around the middle of the spectrum. I have implemented the FFT like so using the *Accelerate* library:

```
func FFT(buffer: [Float]) -> [Float] {

    var real = [Float](buffer)
    var imaginary = [Float](count: buffer.count, repeatedValue: 0.0)
    var splitComplex = DSPSplitComplex(realp: &real, imagp: &imaginary)

    let length = vDSP_Length(floor(log2(Float(buffer.count))))
    let radix = FFTRadix(kFFTRadix2)
    let setup: FFTSetup = vDSP_create_fftsetup(length, radix)

    vDSP_fft_zrip(setup, &splitComplex, 1, length, FFTDirection(FFT_FORWARD))

    //Extracting the magnitudes: real^2 + imag^2
    var magnitudes = [Float](count: buffer.count, repeatedValue: 0.0)
    vDSP_zvmags(&splitComplex, 1, &magnitudes, 1, vDSP_Length(buffer.count))

    var normalizedMagnitudes = [Float](count: buffer.count, repeatedValue: 0.0)
    vDSP_vsmul(sqrt(magnitudes), 1, [2.0 / Float(buffer.count)], &normalizedMagnitudes, 1, vDSP_Length(buffer.count))

    return normalizedMagnitudes

}
```

The Spectral centroid algorithm that I've implemented looks like so:

```
func spectralCentroid(fft: [Float]) -> Float {

    var numerator: Float = 0;
    var denominator: Float = 0;

    var nyquist: Int = fft.count/2;

    for (index, bin) in enumerate(Array(fft[0..<nyquist])){
        numerator += (abs(bin)*Float(index))
    }
    denominator = sum(Array(fft[0..<nyquist]));

    return isnan(numerator/denominator) ? 0 : (numerator/denominator)/Float(nyquist);
}
```

I am also using this utility function that I've made to convert from AVAudioPCMBuffer to a regular float buffer:

```
func convertBufferToFloat(buffer: AVAudioPCMBuffer) -> [Float]{

    for var i: Int = 0; i < Int(buffer.frameLength); i++ {
        bufferInFloat[i] = buffer.floatChannelData.memory[i]
    }

    return bufferInFloat
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: A few remarks. If you have a uniform noise floor, that would make the centroid stick to 1/2, and this effect would get stronger with higher noise levels. Also, you should take the centroid over the magnitude-squared distribution, instead the magnitude distribution. This is mathematically better behaved in many ways and the more natural choice considering the nature of the vector space you're working it as it is invariant under the choice of a basis expansion. Switching to squared magnitude summing will also improve your results as the noise floor will decrease.

Comment: @Jazzmaniac, thanks. How can I check if I have a uniform noise floor? I am grabbing the PCM data straight from the computer microphone using AVFoundation.

Comment: You can plot the spectrum for starters. Best with logarithmic amplitude scaling.